How to add local package to local registry in Cargo?
I am developing set of library crates for personal use. I want to reuse them in several projects of mine. I do not want to publish the libraries or final projects anywhere to the internet as they are for my personal use only (university tasks).
I  don't like to specify path dependencies as paths may look like: ../../../library-crates/project. So path dependencies are not an option for me!
Tried
While workspace works great for set of closely related projects, they do not fit the idea of separating projects by subject in uni. Each subject already has dedicated workspace with set of appropriate crates.
I am aware of path dependencies. I use them within workspace. But as of me they are not suitable to for specifying dependencies external to workspace.
Source replacement sounds great, but official docs mention only vendoring, that is copying external dependencies to local-registry or directory. They do not mention how to add locally developed, unpublished crate to local registry.
Some other ecosystems support notion of local registry, namely: maven, npm. They allow you to add your own locally developed packages to local registry. Later you can reuse these packages in other project as regular dependency, without specifying obscure paths.
Cargo does support notion of local registry, but it requires index file. The file implies some configuration. According to official docs the local-registry format is purposed for mirroring over network.
Expectations
I am expecting some easy way to reuse locally developed libraries within other local packages, spread across different workspaces.

DISCLAIMER

currently cargo does not support use case, described in question.
see relevant github issue: https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/13708

Original answer
Local registry configuration
Create folder which will contain local packages
mkdir ~/cargo-local

Configure local source for our local packages. The configuration file should be located at ~/.cargo/config.toml:
[source.local]
directory = "cargo-local"

[source.cargo-io]
replace-with = "local"

replace-with instructs cargo to redirect all download requests to specified source. This may lead to dependency resolution issues!
directory tells cargo where to look for local registry and that the registry is plain directory.

Note, that relative directory path is resolved relative to ../ directory, that is directory containing .cargo folder!

The next step is to add locally developed library to local registry. Cargo vendor command is not suitable for this, because it copy only dependencies of a project, not the project itself.
From crate's root (not workspace's root by crate's) do the following:
echo "{files:{}}" > .cargo-checksum.json
cp -r . ~/cargo-local

We have to add .cargo-checksum.json file by ourself. Its content should be the following:
{"files":{}}

THIS STEP IS DONE BY echo ... COMMAND ABOVE!!!
Cargo requires this file to always be present with content at least as above.
Finally, add dependency to other project as usual:
[dependencies]
local-package = { version = "0.1.0", registry = "local" }

